# Error: Access is denied при работе с AJAX ie9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Скрипты работают во всех браузерах, кроме ie9, ie8. 
Сначала была ошибка

`No Transport`

Я написал

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

А потом вот эта ошибка `Error: Access is denied`

Comment: [IE9 jQuery AJAX with CORS returns “Access is denied”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10232313/2881286)

Answer (score 0):

Помогло, дописав `dataType: 'jsonp',`